# AICc(): Error with logLik, cannot apply to object of class 'logical'

Tags: r, glmmtmb

I'm trying to get an AICc table for a few of my models which were constructed using package glmmTMB. The model gives a logLik value but no AICc. When I put the model into AICc():

```
a <- print(AICc(model, trace = TRUE, 
                rank = "AICc", REML = FALSE))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
  no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

I have used other functions like AICtab() and have gotten the same error, so I believe it is in the model itself. If anyone is able to interpret this error here please let me know, thank you.

Edit:

Minimal dataset and model used:

```
ID <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C") 
#random effect
Sesh <- c("A1","B1","C1","A2","B2","C2","A3","B3","C3","A4","B4","C4") 
#nested random effect
Stim <- c("Old","New","Old","New","Old","New","Old","New","Old","New","Old","New")
Temp <- c(75, 76, 72, 80, 71, 65, 69, 60, 76, 80, 81, 60)
Total <- c(0,1,5,6,3,10,2,1,0,0,4,6)
z <- data.frame(ID, Sesh, Stim, Temp, Total)

m <- glmmTMB(
  Total ~ Stim + Temp + (1|ID/Sesh),
  ziformula = ~1,
  data = z,
  family = nbinom2)
```

Comment: It might be hard to debug this. Could you please add a sample model whose `AIC` you expect to obtain. Maybe use a very minimal dataset for reproducibility?

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I just added a sample model and dataset, hope this helps.

Comment: On reading the docs, this seems like a data issue.It seems AICc is only possible for larger samples. However, this is my first time meeting this metric so I am not statistically qualified to answer.  I have provided ways to extract it all the same.

Comment: Are you sure about this ```(1|ID/Sesh)```. Looking at your example above, Sesh is embedded inside ID. You only need ID. Sesh is overspecified (no replicates)

Answer (score 1):

Your model does not have likelihood (`logLik(m)` is `NA`), so it is impossible to calculate any likelihood-based criterion from it. This is presumably due to small sample size for a model with zero-inflation (the same model without `ziformula` gives `logLik`).

Also note that `AICc` (I assume it is `MuMIn::AICc`) does not have arguments `trace`, `rank` nor `REML`, hence the error. I believe you confused the command with `dredge`.

Comment: Thank you so much - this was the answer. My data set is actually a lot larger than this and returns a logLik, so when I ran it with using dredge I got the needed AICc table. Interestingly enough, it was very close to my AIC values, which I did not expect. Again, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

We can extract it manually(see **NOTE**):

```
summary(m)$AICtab
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
      NA       NA       NA       NA        5
```

To directly get the AIC:

```
summary(m)$AICtab[[1]]
[1] NA
```

**To get the AICc**(I have not encountered this criteria in my studies at the time of writing):

```
MuMIn::AICc(m)
[1] NA
```

It is however the same output as above.

**NOTE**

- It seems the developer(s) did not implement an `AIC` method for `glmmTMB` models so using `AIC` fails.
- The above AIC is NA likely due to insufficient data. This answer is just to show how to extract the AIC manually.
  From the docs of `AICc`:

> Calculate Second-order Akaike Information Criterion for one or several fitted model objects (AICc, AIC for small samples).

Comment: Hi Nelson, thanks - I do receive all values for AICtab when I get the summary for my model. When I use MuMin::AICc() function like you suggested here, I receive the AIC value as opposed to the AICc value, which I believe you have to specify. I do believe that AICc is for smaller sample models, which is why I am using that over AIC.

Comment: From the docs of that function, `AICc` is suggested for larger samples see the last quote in my "answer". Interesting discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86768/aicc-for-small-sample-sizes) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319769/is-aicc-ever-worse-than-aic). It seems the docs of that function are erroneous or at least use a different method although the note states otherwise. I conclude that you should consult at Cross Validated

Comment: I'm using AICc on this set of data because it is on the smaller side - on the second page you linked it says that AIC and AICc begin to converge as the sample size gets larger, however as my sample size is small, AICc is the way to go. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It's probably an error with the nested part of your model. See [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/troubleshooting.html) to fix it. I'm not statistically qualified(yet) to know how to redefine this model. Cannot get AICc since LogLik is `NA`.